# date writing in csv file error

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to write a date in a csv file (excel) using pythom 3.3 here is my code

```
date=["16.02.2018", "blah"]
CSVreport = open('indata.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(CSVreport)
with open('indata.csv', 'w+') as ou_f:
    ou_f.write([str(date,'UTF-8')])
with open('indata.csv', 'r') as in_f:
    ou_f_content = in_f.read().decode('UFT-8')
#wr.writerow (bytes(date,'UTF-8'))
CSVreport.close()
```

an it gives me the error in the title I don't know what's wrong so if you can help I will be thankfull

Comment: What is the error, and why are you reading the file you want to write?

Comment: Please include the _complete_ error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least four problems, three of which are on the line `ou_f.write([str(date,'UTF-8')])`.

- First, `date` is a list and you cannot convert a list to a string with `str()`.
- Second, you pass a list to `ou_f.write()`, but it requires a string.
- Third, you opened the CSV file in the binary mode.
- Fourth, you created a CSV writer but never used it. Using the CSV writer solves the first two problems:

-

```
with open('indata.csv', 'w') as CSVreport:
    wr = csv.writer(CSVreport)
    wr.writerow(date)
```

Answer (score -2):

u mispelled utf on your write line

also check out the struct module for packing and unpacking binary data, which is what utf8 encoding does. you can check to see what you're actually passing to the write() function, also i think your script itself has to be utf8 encoded

'w' opens for ascii pack/unpack, 'wb' writes the data as you pass it. 'w' is pretty much a shortcut for python to do the packing internally for ascii. if you're writing utf-8 data you should research if 'w' can handle this correctly. and its questionable if you even need to use utf-8. ascii covers 256 characters which includes the american date/time notation. also,           why not close the file?

Comment: first thank you for your reply and also I am new in python so can you please show me how to make the code right

Comment: The OP has nothing to do with packing/unpacking.